# iOS: RTSP player through web app

Tags: ios, web-applications, stream, rtsp

I know this question has been asked many times and here I am again. I want to create an app to stream video on iPhone through RTSP. My research shows me that there are apps on app store using RTSP but there's no tutorial or easy method to do it. If there is please let me know.

I've come across the idea of building webapps for mobile devices using Frameworks like Sencha. And I thought why not use html5 to build my app.  But as I have no particular experience in the field I wanted to ask the experts and see if it really is possible. Can I build my RTSP player for iPhone using Sencha or any other similar framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Senha, but we do build apps using rtsp, we have both frameworks and tutorials. I would say most if not all applications in the  app store's that act as rtsp clients use ffmpeg an open source streaming library.

Players have been built using our framework 
http://www.streammore.tv

live 555 http://www.livemedia.com

openCV , http://www.opencv.org

here is a little tutorial to help you get started

http://sol3.typepad.com/exotic_particles/

Comment: thanks michelle!! I see that the tutorial is incomplete, can you please tell me when will we have the complete tutorial?

Comment: I can't say, we really enjoy helping the open source effort, but we only do tutorials when we have time between our revenue generating work. I'm sure you understand. You are welcome to join our Facebook group http://www.facebook.com/groups/mooncatventures/ were we can offer more advise or if your interested discuss consulting.

Comment: yes I do understand. Actually what I want right now is just get and play rtsp feed so I asked. but thanks anyway.

Comment: Visit the above link if you have Facebook otherwise email me I am sure we can get you some kind of tutorial

Comment: I'll send you an email. I'm really grateful for this!!